# Powershell and Mongo API

Tags: powershell

I did a script in the last days to create collection (with this cmdlet https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc) and Database User and Role with mongo atlas api via powershell. Script works fine but I have not been able to make a control to check if a collection already exist (I can check environment on csv to create object in correct environment). So, for example, if I run the script to create in the same environment two role on the same collection, I got error that collection exist:

[image]

How can I do a control to check, in all environment, and skip collection creation if existent? Here the code involved:

```
    $filepath = "namecsv.csv" 
$listas = Import-CSV $filepath -delimiter ";" 
foreach ($lista in $listas) {                      
  $db = $lista.db
  $collection = $lista.collection
  $rolename = $lista.roleName
#dev
if ($rolename -imatch '_DV_' ) {
     Connect-Mdbc -ConnectionString "mongodb+srv://username:password@onnectionstring"
                $dbc = Get-MdbcDatabase -Name $db
                Add-MdbcCollection -Name $collection -Database $dbc
                Write-Host "Collection $collection creata sul db $db di dev" -ForegroundColor Green               
}
#test
if ($rolename -imatch '_TS_') {
     Connect-Mdbc -ConnectionString "mongodb+srv://username:password@onnectionstring"
                $dbc = Get-MdbcDatabase -Name $db
                Add-MdbcCollection -Name $collection -Database $dbc    
                Write-Host "Collection $collection creata sul db $db di test" -ForegroundColor Green

}
#uat
if ($rolename -imatch '_UT_') {
     Connect-Mdbc -ConnectionString "mongodb+srv://username:password@onnectionstring"
                $dbc = Get-MdbcDatabase -Name $db
                Add-MdbcCollection -Name $collection -Database $dbc   
                Write-Host "Collection $collection creata sul db $db di uat" -ForegroundColor Green

}  
#prod
if ($rolename -imatch '_PR_') {
     Connect-Mdbc -ConnectionString "mongodb+srv://username:password@onnectionstring"
                $dbc = Get-MdbcDatabase -Name $db
                Add-MdbcCollection -Name $collection -Database $dbc
                Write-Host "Collection $collection creata sul db $db di prod" -ForegroundColor Green

}
}
```

Here is how the csv is structured:

```
  db     collection  roleName
  dbname collection1 GROUPNAME_DV_RW
  dbname collection1 GROUPNAME_DV_RO
```

If can help, here what I get with cmdlet get-mdbc collection:

[Get-MdbcCollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAR1e.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You almost figured out this. Use the following code:

```bsh
# get all collections
$dbcol = Get-MdbcCollection -Database dbs

# get/check the collection "test" (it is $null if it does not exist)
$colTest = $dbcol | Where-Object {$_.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName -ceq "test"}
```

Note that `Get-MdbcCollection test` always returns a non-null collection objects, existing or not (but ready to operate on regardless).

Answer (score 0):

thanks roman for the helps but that code did't working (maybe i don't understand where to put), so i modified "if" as following and now script do what i want:

```
if ($rolename -imatch '_TS_') {

 Connect-Mdbc -ConnectionString "mongodb+srv://username:password@connectionstring"
 #### GET COLLECTIONS ###
 $dbtest = Get-MdbcDatabase -name $db
 $colltest = Get-MdbcCollection -Database $dbtest 

    if ($colltest.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName -ceq $collection) {

            Write-Host "Collection $collection esistente su $db di TEST" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
else {

        Add-MdbcCollection -Name $collection -Database $dbtest 
        Write-Host "Collection $collection creata sul db $db di TEST" -ForegroundColor Green

    }
}
```

thanks also for your cmdlet :)